# Controlling Expansion of Functions

Tags: function-construction

Suppose I had the following definitions

```
const /: N[const] = 1 / Pi^2;
f /: N[f[x_]] := const / x^2;
g /: N[g[x_]] := Pi * Sqrt[f[x]] * x^2;
```

Now for this example, it is clear that `g[x] == x` for all values of `x`, but let's suppose there's a outside reason for defining these functions in this way.

Is there a way of controlling the expansion of `g` so that the result is in terms of `f`?  For example, suppose I wanted to to simplify `g[x] / f[x]` while remaining `f` symbolic.  The use of `N` unfortunately expanded everything which is not what I want.

I have tried using `Inactive`, but so far my attempts have not succeeded and I'm not sure whether there might be a better option.

Comment: Why not `Inactivate`?:  `Inactivate[g[x]/f[x], f] // N`

Comment: In the example above, this is fine; but what if `g[x]` contains a number of other functions which I don't want expanded?  It then becomes a bit more difficult to use `Inactivate` (especially if I don't know a priori what functions went into defining `g[x]`).

Comment: Just `Inactivate` all possible head that you don't want to expand? You may want to read the **Scope** section of document of `Inactivate`.

Comment: I guess using `Inactivate[..., Except[g]]` would work.  If you want to post that as the answer?

Comment: You can post an answer yourself :) .

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @xzczd, one possibility that can work in some conditions is to use `Inactivate` which works very well when there are certain explicit terms that need not be expanded, but it doesn't work terribly well with implicit terms (such as `f` within `g` as it isn't inactivated).  It is possible to use `Block[{f = Inactive[f]}, ...]`, but it still requires knowing the expansion.

I've managed to find another solution (for my use case) by manipulating the up and down values.

Consider the following base definitions:

```
const /: N[const] = 1 / Pi^2;
f[x_?InexactNumberQ] := const / x^2;
g /: N[g[x_]] := Pi * Sqrt[f[x]] * x^2;

Attributes[ExpandValues] = {HoldAll};
ExpandValues[symbol_] := Join @@ Through[
  {OwnValues, DownValues, UpValues, SubValues, DefaultValues, NValues}[symbol]
] /. {
  InexactNumberQ :> (True &),
  HoldPattern[N[f_, __]] :> f
}
ExpandValues[symbol_, symbols__] := Join[ExpandValues[symbol], ExpandValues[symbols]]
```

The definition of `ExpandValues` function looks at the symbol's values to create a list of replacement, and the left hand side of the rules so they can be applied more broadly (for example, but replacing `N[f[x_]]` with just `f[x_]` and removing checks for inexact numbers).

Here are some examples of it being used:

```
g[x] /. ExpandValues[g]
```

> ```
> Pi x^2 Sqrt[f[x]]
> ```

```
g[x] / f[x] //. ExpandValues[g]
```

> ```
> Pi x^2 / Sqrt[f[x]]
> ```

```
g[x] / f[x] //. ExpandValues[g, f]
```

> ```
> Pi Sqrt[const / x^2] x^4 / const
> ```