# Replace Condition in Replacement Rules

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

In finding an answer to [my other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/229726/2440), I'm finding myself needing to manipulate the conditions imposed on replacement rules, but this is proving to be a little difficult.  In particular, how should I go about removing instances of `Condition` and `PatternTest`?

Using the code from my other answer (slightly adjusted):

```
f[x_?InexactNumberQ] := x^2;
g[x_] /; FooQ[x] := x^3;

Attributes[ExpandValues] = {HoldAll};
ExpandValues[symbol_] := Join @@ Through[
  {OwnValues, DownValues, UpValues, SubValues, DefaultValues, NValues}[symbol]
];
ExpandValues[symbol_, symbols__] := Join[ExpandValues[symbol], ExpandValues[symbols]];
```

then the replacement rules that need to be modified are:

```
{
  HoldPattern[f[(x_)?InexactNumberQ]] :> x^2,
  HoldPattern[g[x_] /; FooQ[x]] :> x^3
}
```

I would like these to be modified to not have any conditions on the arguments, but trying to replace the condition and pattern test is proving difficult.  This for example does not work:

```
{
  HoldPattern[Condition[p_, q_]] :> p,
  HoldPattern[PatternTest[p_, q_]] :> p
}
```

I've also tried using [`Verbatim`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Verbatim.html) which the documentation suggests is useful to transform other transformation rules, but I have not gotten them to work.  I'm also thinking that the use of Verbatim won't work generally because it is too literal.

I've had partial success with

```
{
  Condition -> (#1 &),
  PatternTest -> (#1 &)
}
```

but when the replacement appears within a `HoldPattern`, the resulting rule after replacement does not work.

Comment: `{HoldPattern[f[(x_)?InexactNumberQ]] :> x^2,  HoldPattern[g[x_] /; FooQ[x]] :> x^3} /. (Condition | PatternTest)[ p_, q_] :> p` works.

Comment: Interesting that this works, but if you split the two alternatives into their own rules then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, not sure how you used it, but I think what you need is exactly `Verbatim`:

```
{HoldPattern[f[(x_)?InexactNumberQ]] :> x^2, HoldPattern[g[x_] /; FooQ[x]] :> x^3} /. 
  {Verbatim[Condition][p_, q_] :> p, Verbatim[PatternTest][p_, q_] :> p}

(*
  {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x^2, HoldPattern[g[x_]] :> x^3}
 *)
```

---

Inspired by [kglr's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230206/replace-condition-in-replacement-rules#comment583895_230206) above, another approach is to place `Condition` and `PatternTest` into `Pattern`:

```
{HoldPattern[f[(x_)?InexactNumberQ]] :> x^2, HoldPattern[g[x_] /; FooQ[x]] :> x^3} /. 
  {(a : Condition)[p_, q_] :> p, (a : PatternTest)[p_, q_] :> p}
```

Comment: Wow, that's simple... I was indeed using `Verbatim` wrong by applying to the whole condition (`Verbatim[Condition[p_, q_]]`).  I didn't realise it could be applied to just the head.

Comment: @JP-Ellis I agree currently the document of `Verbatim` is a bit too brief.